# Why is it not necessary for $a_n$ to be eventually non-positive if $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}a_i$ diverges to-$\infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

When I attempted this question I thought that it was necessary but I’m not sure why it’s not necessary because if I take for example

$$a_n = \begin{cases}-(2)^n&\text{if $n$ is odd}\\\frac{1}{2}& \text{if $n$ is even}\end{cases}$$

Would the sum of this sequence diverge to minus infinity? So would this show that $a_n$ does not have to be non-positive eventually?

Comment: I think you want divergence to $\infty$ (or a modified example).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That sequence is a valid counterexample. Another one would be:
$$
    a_n = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{$n$ is odd} \\ 
                       -2 & \text{$n$ is even}
          \end{cases}
$$
Notice that the sum of any two consecutive terms is $-1$. So the partial sum can be expressed in closed form:
$$
    \sum_{k=1}^n a_n = \begin{cases} 
                           -\frac{n}{2} & \text {$n$ is even} \\
                           -\frac{n}{2} + \frac{3}{2} & \text{$n$ is odd} 
    \end{cases}
$$
Then you can show that the partial sums tend to $-\infty$ as $n\to\infty$.